# suppress password prompt on weblogic server startup

Tags: java, security, weblogic

How do we  suppress password prompt on weblogic server startup?. The password prompt comes while starting production mode of weblogic server. At this time user should enter the username and password of weblogic server.

So it is giving problem on

- automatic start weblogic when server is rebooted.
- to execute wlst command .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not using nodemanager to startup the servers:

1. Create a file named boot.properties at $domain_home/security/boot.properties with the following content
2. `username=<USERNAME>
    password=<PASSWORD>`
3. Start the server now and it will automatically pickup the username/password from this file. The server will also encrypt the file.
4. [Reference](http://onlineappsdba.com/index.php/2010/08/21/weblogic-startup-prompting-from-username-password-bootproperties/)

If you are using nodemanager to startup the servers:

1. You need to enroll the server to the nodemanager and the boot.properties file will be automatically created at $domain_home/servers/server_name/data/nodemanager/
2. [Reference](http://weblogicfordummies.blogspot.in/2009/07/node-manager-in-oracle-weblogic-server.html)